# Views hook_views_query_alter JOIN

Tags: join, drupal-7, drupal-views

In hook_views_query_alter i build join query like this:

```
$join = new views_join();
$join->table = 'table_2';
$join->field = 'field_2';
$join->left_table = 'table_1';
$join->left_field = 'field_1';
$join->type = 'LEFT';
$join->extra = array(
  array(
     'table' => 'table_2',
     'field' => 'field_3',
     'value' => 'table_1.field_4',
  ),
);
```

The query should looks like this:

```
LEFT JOIN {table_2} table_2 ON table_1.field_1 = table_2.field_2 AND table_1.field_3 = table_2.field_4
```

My problem is here **'value' => 'table_1.field_4'**. I can't set value as field. It treat it as string value. So at the and in my query i have unwanted single quotes.

So at the end my query looks like this:

```
LEFT JOIN {table_2} table_2 ON table_1.field_1 = table_2.field_2 AND table_1.field_3 = 'table_2.field_4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best solution but this:

```
$join = new views_join();
$join->table = 'table_2';
$join->field = 'field_2';
$join->left_table = 'table_1';
$join->left_field = 'field_1';
$join->type = 'LEFT';

$join->extra = 'table_1.field_3 = table_2.field_4';
```

works for me.